# activating screen sharing remotely

Tags: remote-control, screen-sharing

There is a computer I don't have immediate access to that I cannot screenshare with it. I have an account on the computer and have screenshared before with it.

I believe some setting has been changed to deactivate screensharing.

Is there a way to activate screensharing through `ssh`?

My computer is OS 10.6.8. I'm not sure what the other one is but probably the same.

Comment: I'm not able to answer right now, but I suspect the solution may involve osascript and the "System Events" application. More later if someone else hasn't already worked out an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To enable remote management (including screensharing), issue the following command over `ssh`:

***Note:*** This command sets your vnc password to 'mypasswd' as set by the `-vncpw` flag in the command, you should change this.

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -access -on -clientopts -setvnclegacy -vnclegacy yes -clientopts -setvncpw -vncpw mypasswd -restart -agent -privs -all
```

---

To disable the remote management, issue the following command over `ssh`:

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -deactivate -configure -access -off
```

Comment: nice. that worked great.