# Editing iMac settings from an external Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, display

My 2010 iMac's display shows up distorted lines on start up then gets stuck at the gray Apple logo screen. After being stuck there for a while it then reboots itself and does the same process over again until I force shutdown. Fortunately I have a MacBook Pro in which I can use to boot from and view the files from my iMac this way. I believe my iMac is having graphics issues but I have an external monitor I would like to use to view my iMac. Is it possible to configure the settings for my iMac from my MacBook Pro so that I can set my iMac to display via the external monitor and if not are there any alternatives?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This *sounds* like either a graphics card failure or a logic board failure: I would recommend *getting the data off that drive **ASAP*** and look at getting that machine diagnosed and repaired.

Answer (score 0):

If you have at least remote logins enabled, you can use the answer to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26698/activating-screen-sharing-remotely) to enable Screen Sharing and accessing your iMac from the MacBookPro.

If you already have Screen Sharing enabled, you can use this directly to access your iMac.